# Adding external Graphics library in Ubuntu10.04

Tags: c, graphics, plot, ubuntu-10.04

i am a beginner to c progmmng, right nw m coding c on ubuntu using gedit and compiling in gcc, i want to plot a graph in c prog, i read regarding gnuplot and koolplot, but when i include those files in my prog i get output as: fatal error/no such directory etc..can anyone tell me how to work it out..please give in detail ans..coz m new to using ubuntu...
i appreciate your answers thankx

Comment: Post relevant code snippets / copy paste the errors. You'll get more answers.

Answer (score 0):

How did you install gnuplot and how are you using it in your program?  Did you follow the instructions in the [gnuplot manual](http://ndevilla.free.fr/gnuplot/gnuplot_i/index.html)?

Koolplot appears to be designed for the MingW environment under Windows, I wouldn't recommend using it if you're in a Linux environment.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use GPL library [MathGL](http://mathgl.sf.net/)? It is cross-platform, have C interface and is specially designed as plotting library (not an external program). However it has external GUI and console tools too.